# Limit number of displayed rows in a table (while including all in the summary)

Tags: r, gt

I want to create a table with the gt package in R. I want to include **summary row that calculate the sum of all rows in the set**. However, as the data set is very big and contains more than 100 rows for each exporter, I **only want 5 rows of each exporter to be displayed in the table**.

This is the code of my table:

```
table5 <- df4 %>% 
  group_by(exporter) %>%
  gt(rowname_col = "FVA_origin", groupname_col = "exporter") %>%
  tab_header(
    title = "FVA Origin of SADC's exports in the transport equipment sector",
    subtitle = "(by shares of total exports)"
  ) %>%
  tab_source_note(
    source_note = "Source: Data created from Eora MRIO according to the algorithm of Borin & Mancini (2020)."
  ) %>%
  # Change column names
  cols_label(
    "FVA_origin_1999_2002" = "FVA origin",
    "FYavgShares_1999_2002" = "1999-2002",
    "FYavgShares_2003_2006" = "2003-2006",
    "FYavgShares_2007_2010" = "2007-2010",
    "FYavgShares_2011_2014" = "2011-2014",
    "FYavgShares_2015_2018" = "2015-2018"
  ) %>%
  # add tab headers
  tab_spanner(
    label =  md('**Share of exports**'),
    columns = c("FYavgShares_1999_2002", "FYavgShares_2003_2006", "FYavgShares_2007_2010", "FYavgShares_2011-_2014", "FYavgShares_2015_2018")
    ) %>%
  summary_rows(
    groups = everything(),
    fns = list(
      'Total' = ~sum(as.numeric(.))
    ),
    formatter = fmt_number,
    decimals = 1,
    side = "top"
  )
```

**What I tried:**

- If I include head(10) in the beginning, the dataset only shows me the first 10 rows for one exporter. However, I want the first 10 rows of every exporter to be displayed.
- slice_head(n = 5) at the same spot does not include all rows in the summary column.
- Applying slice_head(n = 5) and slice(n = 5) is not accepted within the gt function itself.

Here is a **sample** of my data:

```
exporter <- c("AGO", "BWA", "COD")
FVA_origin_1999_2002 <- c("CHN", "ALB", "DZA", "AND", "AGO", "USA", "ARG", "ARM", "ABW", "AUS", "AFG", "SWZ", "DZA", "AND", "AGO", "ATG", "ARG", "ARM", "ABW", "AUS", "AFG", "ALB", "DZA", "AND", "LSO", "ATG", "ARG", "ARM", "ABW", "GER")
FYavgShares_1999_2002 <- c(5:34)
FYavgShares_2003_2006 <- c(6:35)
FYavgShares_2007_2010 <- c(7:36)
FYavgShares_2011_2014 <- c(5:34)
FYavgShares_2015_2018 <- c(4:33)

# Corrected column name
sample <- data.frame(exporter, FVA_origin_1999_2002, FYavgShares_1999_2002, FYavgShares_2003_2006, FYavgShares_2007_2010, FYavgShares_2011_2014, FYavgShares_2015_2018)
```

Comment: I can't load the example data since `exporter` is 3 items but the other variables have 10 items, not a multiple of 3. And when I load the data using the code above, I get columns like `FVA_origin_1999.2002` in place of `FVA_origin_1999-2002`.